# Does @RequestMapping(produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8") block jsonp requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm trying to debug a problem on production server where there's a method inside a controller that is annotated by:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
```

And in javascript an ajax call is made to this endpoint:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: "<%=endpointUrl%>",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data){
                console.log("success!");
            },
            error: function(xhr, options, error){
                console.log("fail!");
            }
});
```

But in chrome I get warning for Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response ... with MIME type application/json.

I thought jsonp is used to 'bypass' same-origin-policy for get requests? Why is it getting blocked?

EDIT: additional info, these headers are set in the endpoint:

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'");
httpResponse.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
httpResponse.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change jsonp to json as your server is returning content type JSON but not jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
```

change to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/javascript;charset=utf-8")
```

---

The problem is caused by

```
httpResponse.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
```

enforcing content-type